# Android - how to set a thumbnail on a VideoView with a uri source?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I need to get an image from a uri into my VideoView when it loads. It should disappear and start playing the video when play is hit. This is my VideoView code -

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#000"
    >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_media_play"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I use it -

```
final VideoView video = (VideoView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.video);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(submission.getUrl());
    video.setVideoURI(uri);

    final ImageButton playButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (video.isPlaying()){
            }else{
                video.start();
                playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`VideoView` shows a video. It does not show an image. Similarly, `ImageView` shows an image. It does not show a video.

So, use a `FrameLayout` wrapped around an `ImageView` and a `VideoView`. Have the `ImageView` be visible and the `VideoView` be invisible at the outset. Load the image into the `ImageView`. When the user clicks your play button, switch the visibility such that the `VideoView` is now visible and the `ImageView` is invisible, and start playback of your video.

Comment: my question is probably a bit unclear.. I need for a way to extract an image out of the video itself.. not sure if this is possible.

Comment: @Suchi: If the video is known to `MediaStore`, it should have a thumbnail which you can retrieve, typically via an image-loading library (see [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Media/VideoList)). If the video is not known to `MediaStore`, [`ThumbnailUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) should be able to extract one, though I have not used it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a thumpnail of video and show it on ImageView. In case you need to show play button you need another ImageView (with Play button icon). On click of Play icon image view play the video on VideoView.

```
    imageView.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(urlPath, 
    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have created an `ImageView` for thumbnail like this**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

 <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/videoView_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And add `setOnPreparedListener` and `setOnCompletionListener` in Java like this way**

```
  VideoView videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
  ImageView thumbnailView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.videoView_thumbnail);

  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(your_Image_Path).into(thumbnailView);
 //you can add progress dialog here until video is start playing;

    mediaController= new MediaController(getContext());
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    videoView.setVideoPath(your_video_path);
    videoView.start();         //call this method for auto playing video

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            thumbnailView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 //you can Hide progress dialog here when video is start playing;

        }
    });
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            videoView.stopPlayback();
            thumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

It works for me very well. I hope it's useful for all.